# GoogleMaps on Android reverts to standard GoogleMap tiles (as opposed to my custom ones) when switched to landscape mode?

Tags: android, google-maps, orientation, landscape, portrait

I've declared my GoogleMap object and set it up with the option

```
map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
```

So it shouldn't even be trying to load the GoogleMap tiles! Everything works just fine so long as I don't change the screen orientation. As soon as I go from landscape to portrait or the other way around, GoogleMaps starts loading the standard GoogleMaps tiles and not the custom tile set I've specified. Once again, my custom tiles run perfectly fine if I don't change the orientation. Anyone know anything about this?

Comment: Where do you do `map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);`? When you rotate your device, Android re-create your `Activity` and `Fragment`.

Comment: Do you mean that when I rotate it onCreate() gets called again? Because that's where I instantiate the map and call on a method that sets the type to NONE.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by moving the gmap stuff back into the mainactivity code (as opposed to a custom class). Still not sure why this works. Oh well.